# Saving to the database a model icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating an article but if the user wants, it will create a single comment, according to the a text_field_tag decide that the user decide or not. The comment would not be related to the current article

In the controller, event.create i have the following logic

```
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comment.article_id = params[:decide].to_i
  @comment.customer_id = current_customer.id
  @comment.description = params[:description]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
    else
    end
  end
```

The issue i have is i get a response of else, meaning i cant save it, and i don't understand why, what does save call?

I also note that comment create option has the default line in each action.

```
@article= Article.find(params[:event_id])
```

I am just wondering if comment.save call a method in my comment controller, or does save just save it straight the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@comment.save` tries to save your comment to the database. If everything is alright it will save it and you would write something like `redirect_to root_path`.

If it doesn't manage to save it it will go to the `else` clause and there you will have also the option to redirect somewhere or even better, render the view page where you where and be able to write the error log.

One of the reasons why it wouldn't be saved is if it's not getting the parameters right or if it's not passing some validation.

Comment: Would there be a way to verify if save parameters are correct of some sort? as a console maybe?

Comment: To find out about the errors, write the save method with a bang at the end => `save!` . Then it will raise an exception if the record is invalid, and you will see it on the page.

Comment: This is good if you want to test if everything is okay at the moment, but it is not good to have this code usually cause when user doesn't put any description, and lets say that you require the description to be present, it will raise that exception and throw you on a non-desired page giving the user inappropriate unnecessary  error logs.

Comment: No thank you, i knew i was close, and now everything look good now. thkx